# Angular 8 rxjs get values from multiple observables

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I am using rxjs switchMap to get the latest form value from a subject, set a local variable and then perform a query based on that value.

Long story short I am populating select box options based on the current value of the form.

```
  // Get current value of Record Form
  this.recordFormService.recordForm$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(recordForm => {
        // Get current Product Owner on Record Form
        this.currentProductOwner = recordForm.value.ProductOwner;

        // Search People
        return this.recordsApiService.searchPeople$(this.currentProductOwner);
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error(`get recordForm$ failed ${err}`);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    )
    .subscribe(results => {
      // Set Product Owners select box options
      this.productOwners = results.data;
    });
```

This is all working properly.

However, I also need to perform the same exact logic when a specific form value changes.

```
// Run the same logic when the ProductOwner value changes
this.parentFormGroup.controls['ProductOwner'].valueChanges.subscribe(val => {});
```

I tried putting the combineLatest operator at the top, however that only resolves when both observables have emitted at least one value.

The `valueChanges` observable may not necessarily ever change, but recordFormService.recordForm$ will run at least once when the page is loaded.

Note: The result of the `valueChanges` observable is a string and the result of the `recordForm$` observable is a FormGroup object, they need to be processed entirely differently.

What operator can I use to achieve this requirement?

```
// Get latest value of all observables
combineLatest(
  this.parentFormGroup.controls['ProductOwner'].valueChanges,
  // Get current value of Record Form
  this.recordFormService.recordForm$
)
.pipe(
  switchMap(recordForm => {
    // Get current Product Owner on Record Form
    this.currentProductOwner = recordForm.value.ProductOwner;

    // Search People
    return this.recordsApiService.searchPeople$(this.currentProductOwner);
  }),
  catchError(err => {
    console.error(`get recordForm$ failed ${err}`);
    return throwError(err);
  })
)
.subscribe(results => {
  // Set Product Owners select box options
  this.productOwners = results.data;
});
```

UPDATE:

I also tried `merge`. However the results of both observables are entirely different (one is a formGroup and one is a string) and they both need to be processed differently.

```
// Get latest value of all observables
merge(
  this.parentFormGroup.controls['ProductOwner'].valueChanges,
  // Get current value of Record Form
  this.recordFormService.recordForm$
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html):

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
```

Make 2 observables that emit the same type from the observables you want to react to. I am using a fake type `RecordForm` which holds your form value and the product owner as an example:

```
const ownerChanges$: Observable<RecordForm> = this.parentFormGroup.controls['ProductOwner'].valueChanges.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.recordFormService.recordForm$),
  map(([owner, recordForm]) => ({ ...recordForm, owner }))
);
const formChanges$: Observable<RecordForm> = this.recordFormService.recordForm$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.parentFormGroup.controls['ProductOwner'].valueChanges),
  map(([recordForm, owner]) => ({ ...recordForm, owner }))
);
```

Then pass them to merge:

```
// Get latest value of all observables
merge(ownerChanges$, recordChanges$).pipe(
  ...
  // the type passed here is always RecordForm - react accordingly
)
.subscribe(results => {
  // Set Product Owners select box options
  this.productOwners = results.data;
});
```

But you'll want to make sure both observables passed to `merge` are the same type, so they can be handled the same way.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that too, but how do I know the difference between the first and second observable in the `results`?

Comment: Ah ok yes that was my issue, the values are entirely different so I wasn't sure how to process them (one of them is a formGroup and the other is a string).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is create another downstream observable; the one for your form input that should trigger the API call as well as the original observable. To do this you can use `mergeMap` pipe on the original Observable. This will create another Emitter inside that can emit in parallel from the first. Try this:

```
const formObs$ = this.parentFormGroup.controls['ProductOwner'].valueChanges;

this.recordFormService.recordForm$.pipe(
  // give precedence in the merge callback to the original stream Observable,
  // but if just the second Observable fires here, grab that value and use it to pass downstream
  mergeMap(() => formObs$, (originalValue, formObsValue) => originalValue || formObsValue),
  // now recordForm is either from the original observable, or from your form input
  switchMap(recordForm => {
    this.currentProductOwner = recordForm.value.ProductOwner;

    // Search People
    return this.recordsApiService.searchPeople$(this.currentProductOwner);
  }),
  catchError(err => {
    console.error(`get recordForm$ failed ${err}`);
    return throwError(err);
  })
).subscribe(results => {
  // Set Product Owners select box options
  this.productOwners = results.data;
});
```

I'm making the assumption here that recordForm$ is returning a form value just like your second observable `.valueChanges`. If that's not the case, you'll just need to massage it in the mergeMap 2nd callback function to produce a merged value to the switchMap that you want.

Comment: Thanks! Yes the result of the `valueChanges` observable is a string and the result of the `recordForm$` observable is a FormGroup object, so in this case they need to be processed entirely differently.